# How many elements π in $S_n$ such that $π^2 = e$ (the order of π is 1 or 2)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For example in $S_3$, there are 4, namely: e , (01)(2), (02)(1), and (12)(0).

In $S_4$ , i think there are 1 + 6 + 6 = 13.

The identity e: gives 1,
Permutation in the form of (ab)(c)(d) : 6,
In the form of (ab)(cd) : 6

But i had a feeling it must be 14 or something even... (Because 4! - 13 = 11 which is cannot be partitioned in pairs)
What am i  missing ?

Also, Is there a way to dertermine how many such element in $S_n$ ?

Tnk u in advance

Comment: Your (ab)(cd) type is being counted twice each.

Comment: Ohh right !  Thank u

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760631/finding-number-of-functions-from-a-set-to-itself-such-that-ffx-x and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220052/partition-of-a-set-of-size-n-into-subsets-of-size-1-and-2 and probably several others.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that you can write every element of $S_n$ as a product of disjoint cycles. This gives you an easy way to determine the order of an element. Let $\pi\in S_n$, then

$$\pi=(c_{11}...c_{1t_1})(c_{21}...c_{2t_2})...(c_{m1}...c_{mt_m}).$$

Then to compute the order of $\pi$ we look at the least common multiple of $t_1,...,t_m$. In order for the order of $\pi$ to be $1$ or $2$ we require that $t_1,...,t_m\leq 2$. So we see that if we ignore $1-$cycles an element has order $1$ or $2$ if and only if it is the product of disjoint $2-$cycles (transpositions) or it is $e$ (technically $e$ is the product of no $2-$cycles). This allows us to calculate the number of elements of order $1$ or $2$. We simply count how many ways we can have a product of disjoint transpositions.

For $n=4$ there are $\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\frac{1}{2}=3$ ways to find a product of $2$ $2-$cycles. There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to find a product of $1$ $2-$cycle. Lastly there is $1$ way to find a product of no $2$-cycles. This gives us $10$ elements of order $1$ or $2$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be double-counting the elements of $S_4$ with cycle type $(2, 2)$: There are only three, namely, $(12)(34)$, $(13)(24)$, $(14)(23)$.

---

More generally, a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ satisfies $\sigma^2 = e$, i.e., is an *involution*, if its cycle type contains only $1$'s and $2$'s, that is, if it is a product of (possibly zero) disjoint transpositions.

The number of permutations with $k$ transpositions and $n - 2 k$ fixed points is, in [multinomial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem),
$$\frac{1}{k! (n - 2 k)!}{{n}\choose{1, \ldots, 1, 2, \ldots, 2}} = \frac{n!}{2^k k! (n - 2 k)!} :$$ The multifactorial counts the number of ways to put $n$ labeled elements in $n - k$ bins so that $n - 2 k$ bins have $1$ element and $k$ bins have $2$ elements. The labeling on the bins of a given size are irrelevant, so we divide the multinomial by $k! (n - 2 k)!$ as indicated.

For example, for the given case $n = 4$, we can have

- $k = 0$ transpositions (there are $\frac{1}{0! 4!} {4 \choose{1, 1, 1, 1}} = 1$ of these, namely the identity),
- $k = 1$ transpositions (there are $\frac{1}{1! 2!} {4 \choose{1, 1, 2}} = 6$ of these, the transpositions themselves), or
- $k = 2$ transpositions (there are $\frac{1}{2! 0!} {4 \choose{2, 2}} = 3$ of these, the double transpositions).

Summing over the possible values of $k$ gives a general formula number $T_n$ of involutions in $S_n$:
$$T_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \frac{n!}{2^k k! (n - 2 k)!} .$$
The first few values are $T_1 = 1$, $T_2 = 2$, $T_3 = 4$, $T_4 = 10$, $T_5 = 26$.

This turns out to be a well-known sequence, [A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085), *Number of self-inverse permutations on $n$ letters, also known as involutions; number of standard Young tableaux with $n$ cells*. See that link for other interpretations and various formulas for and identities of this sequence.

For more references, see the second paragraph of the introduction of [this 1957 article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/restricted-partitions-of-finite-sets/8BCF18B01F91EE5158DD8CCCF64FBB9C) by Miksa, Moser, and Wyman.

Comment: The last link is broken...